# iOS converting iPad app to Universal app doesn't show the appIcon for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I'm converting an iPad app project to a Universal app project but the option to add the icon for the iPhone does not appear. Does anyone know how can I add the icon for the iPhone in the AppIcon section?

I'd really appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select any app icon and then open the attributes inspector. There you will find checkmarks for other sizes of icons to be enabled.

[image: Attributes Inspector]